# Input parameter from command line as HEX with N-Bytes

Tags: c++

This code works if number of bytes is equal to 1 only
i would like to print what user inserts from command line 
and number of bytes can be changed later

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void writeToScreen(char *data);
const int NOBYTES = 2;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // Example input is: FFA6 (2 Bytes)
    writeToScreen(argv[1]);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void writeToScreen(char *data){
    for(int j=0;j<NOBYTES;j++){
    unsigned char dat = strtol(data+NOBYTES-j-1, NULL, 16);
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if (dat & 1) 
            cout<<"1";
        else
            cout<<"0";
        dat>>=1;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    }
}

/*
    Can i get the out put to be (FFA6):
    11111111
    10100110
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but should do the trick

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>

...

streamstream ss(data);
string temp;
temp.resize(2);
for (;;)
{
    char temp[2];
    if (! (ss >> temp[0])) break;
    if (! (ss >> temp[1])) break;

    stringstream ss2(temp);
    unsigned int value;
    ss2 >> hex >> value;
    cout << bitset<8>(value) << endl;
}
```

Comment: can i make a loop that will handle the size of bytes?? as a global constant??

Comment: @user2768374 It will work out the number of bytes from the size of data string.

Answer (score 0):

Add the length as a parameter

```
void writeToScreen(char *data, size_t dataLength);
```

use `dataLength` instead of `NOBYTES` inside the function, and call it

```
writeToScreen(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
```

Comment: i tried this method if i enter: FF00, it will print 11110000, 11111111

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what are you trying exactly, but if you want to print the binary value of a character (or a sequence of characters) you could try this:

```
void to_binary(const char *const p, std::size_t bytes)
{
    for (std::size_t byte = 0; byte < bytes; ++byte)
    {
        std::cout << "byte" << byte << ": " ;

        for (std::uint8_t bit = 1; bit; bit <<= 1)
        {
            std::cout << ((p[byte] & bit) ? 1 : 0);
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/BPmH7G), te live example.

Extra advice `writeToScreen` should take the pointer as const, it shows the intent of only reading the value passed.